# Itereate HashMap with HashSet as values

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

I've got HashMap with HashSet as value
How to iterate over it ti reseive result like:

```
   key1
   value1
   value2
   value3
   ...
   key2
   value1
   value2
   value3
   key3
   ...
```

I have something wrong in my code:

```
Map<String, HashSet<String>> remarksMap = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();
//...

Iterator<Map.Entry<String, HashSet<String>>> itr1 = remarksMap.entrySet().iterator();
Iterator<String> itr2 = itr1.next().getValue().iterator();

    while (itr1.hasNext()) {

        System.out.println(itr1.next().getKey());

        while (itr2.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(itr2.next());

        }
    }
```

Currently receiving wrong result like:

```
key1
value1
value2
value3
key2
key3
key4
...
```

Comment: `itr2` never gets a second assignment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize `itr2` with the values of the first element of your map and not with the values of the current element. Adjust it like

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, HashSet<String>>> itr1 = remarksMap.entrySet().iterator();

while (itr1.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, HashSet<String>> entry = itr1.next();
    System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    Iterator<String> itr2 = entry.getValue().iterator();

    while (itr2.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(itr2.next());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need explicit `Iterator`s to do this.

Here's a simplified nested iteration with fast-enumeration:

```
Map<String, HashSet<String>> remarksMap = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();
for (String k: remarksMap.keySet()) {
    System.out.printf("%s%n", k);
    for (String v: remarksMap.get(k)) {
        System.out.printf("\t%s%n", v);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that: I just suggested an edit that was total rubbish.

Comment: @chiastic-security no probs - intercepted ;)

Answer (score 1):

put that `Iterator<String> itr2 = itr1.next().getValue().iterator();` into your loop like this:

```
Map<String, HashSet<String>> remarksMap = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();
//...

Iterator<Map.Entry<String, HashSet<String>>> itr1 = remarksMap.entrySet().iterator();

while (itr1.hasNext()) {

    Map.Entry<String, HashSet<String>> entry = itr1.next();
    System.out.println(entry R.getKey());
    Iterator<String> itr2 = entry .getValue().iterator();

    while (itr2.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(itr2.next());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check following code,

```
    Map<String,HashSet<String>> map = new HashMap<String,HashSet<String>>(); // Map with HashSet as value

    HashSet<String> hashset1 = new HashSet<String>();
    hashset1.add("Midhun");
    hashset1.add("Amal");
    hashset1.add("Ajith");

    HashSet<String> hashset2 = new HashSet<String>();
    hashset2.add("Sooraj");
    hashset2.add("Vinay");
    hashset2.add("Vishnu");

    // Putting data in to Map
    map.put("friends",hashset1);
    map.put("relatives",hashset2);

    for(Entry<String,HashSet<String>> mapEntry : map.entrySet()){
        System.out.println("Key :: "+mapEntry.getKey());
        for(String value : mapEntry.getValue()){
            System.out.println("Value :"+value);
        }
        System.out.println("===================");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your `itr2` assignment to inside your `itr1` `while` loop.

But be careful! Your `System.out.println()` in the outer loop grabs the next key, and your `itr2` assignment currently does the same. Make sure you only call `next()` once each time you go through the loop, or you'll miss some keys.